# Filtering FASTA file based on IDS with Biopython

Tags: python-2.7, bioinformatics, biopython

I am very new to programming in python. I have fasta files containing protein sequences for some plant species.

I would like to filter them based on the number of amino acids each sequence contain. Criteria is those sequences >20 amino acids.

I am able to get the amino acids sequence longer than 20 with the resources on [biopython cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc280). However, when I try to write them on the file, it gives me this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw1WA.png). I am unable to resolve this error. Moreover, I would also like to have the IDs of each sequence in the output file. Please help me!

Code:

```
import Bio
from Bio import SeqIO
for s_record in SeqIO.parse('arabidopsis_thaliana_proteome.ath.tfa','fasta'):
    name = s_record.id
    seq = s_record.seq
    seqLen = len(s_record)
    if seqLen >20:
        desired_proteins=seq
        output_file=SeqIO.write(desired_proteins, "filtered.fasta","fasta")
output_file
```

Input File: [Arabidopsis Thaliana](ftp://ftp.psb.ugent.be/pub/plaza/plaza_public_dicots_03//Fasta/proteome.ath.tfa.gz)

```
>AT5G16970
MTATNKQVILKDYVSGFPTESDFDFTTTTVELRVPEGTNSVLVKNLYLSCDPYMRIRMGKPDPSTAALAQAYTPGQPIQGYGVSRIIESGHPDYKKGDLLWGIVAWEEYSVITPMTHAHFKIQHTDVPLSYYTGLLGMPGMTAYAGFYEVCSPKEGETVYVSAASGAVGQLVGQLAKMMGCYVVGSAGSKEKVDLLKTKFGFDDAFNYKEESDLTAALKRCFPNGIDIYFENVGGKMLDAVLVNMNMHGRIAVCGMISQYNLENQEGVHNLSNIIYKRIRIQGFVVSDFYDKYSKFLEFVLPHIREGKITYVEDVADGLEKAPEALVGLFHGKNVGKQVVVVARE*

>AT4G32100
MATNACKFLCLVLLFAFVTQGYGDDSYSLESLSVIQSKTGNMVENKPEWEVKVLNSSPCYFTHTTLSCVRFKSVTPIDSKVLSKSGDTCLLGNGDSIHDISFKYVWDTSFDLKVVDGYIACS*
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Please output exact error message, as well as example input to replicate error.

Comment: Hi @Vince, I have edited the question, with a snapshot of error and an example input.

Comment: You have set desired_proteins = seq = s_record.seq, which is a string-like Seq object. The write function expects a SeqRecord object, i.e. s_record in your example should work.

Comment: Can you fix the question title (filtering by ID) to match the question itself (filtering by length) please?

Comment: I notice you haven't accepted any answer. If one of them solved your problem, you should consider marking it as "accepted". Note that there is now a beta bioinformatics stackexchange site where this question might receive more answers: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

According to BioPython tutorial here:

http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO

The first parameter to `SeqIO.parse()` should be a file handle, not a file name:

> ```
> from Bio import SeqIO
> with open("example.fasta", "rU") as handle:
>     for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
>         print(record.id)
> ```

This should work:

```
import Bio
from Bio import SeqIO
fh=open('arabidopsis_thaliana_proteome.ath.tfa')
for s_record in SeqIO.parse(fh,'fasta'):
    name = s_record.id
    seq = s_record.seq
    seqLen = len(s_record)
    if seqLen >20:
        desired_proteins=seq
        output_file=SeqIO.write(desired_proteins, "filtered.fasta","fasta")
output_file
fh.close()
```

Comment: SeqIO.parse has accepted a filename or a handle for a long time, but good point - that webpage could be more explicit about this.

Comment: Both this solution and the original will keep over-writing filtered.fasta each time write is called, so the final result with be the it only contains the last long protein. Here it would be simplest to open an output handle before the for-loop, and use that instead.

Comment: UPDATE: SeqIO page updated to show examples with filenames

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [bioawk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) (a modified version of awk useful for bioinformatics) instead of biopython:

```
bioawk -c fastx 'length($seq) > 20 {print ">"$name"\n"$seq}' arabidopsis_thaliana_proteome.ath.tfa > filtered.fasta
```

`-c fastx` tells bioawk to parse the file as fastx/fastq format. This defines a `name` and a `seq` variables that one can use using normal `'condition {action}'` awk syntax.

I'm not sure bioawk is packaged for most linux distributions, but the installation from source is not too complicated:
https://silico-sciences.com/2015/12/13/install-bioawk-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

There is an example doing almost exactly this (filtering for sequences under 300 in length), "Input/Output Example - Filtering by sequence length" on http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO

This goes though the options of building up a list of records in memory, versus a memory efficient generator expression.

A third option is to make multiple calls to SeqIO.write using an output handle:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open("short_seqs.fasta", "w") as out_handle:
    for record in SeqIO.parse("cor6_6.gb", "genbank"):
        if len(record.seq) < 300:
            SeqIO.write(record, out_handle, "fasta")
```

However, this approach is only suitable for simple file formats like FASTA, GenBank, EMBL, where you can keep appending records to an existing file. This is not going to work on things like XML output formats - so the approach shown on the linked page is better (making a single call to SeqIO.write using a generator/iterator of records).